# Windows 10 unresponsive errors

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, windows-services

I run Chrome and every few minutes it becomes unresponsive for several seconds. Occasionally I'll even get "page is unresponsive" dialogues. After no more than half a minute everything is back to normal. My question is, what program will monitor my system and tell me exactly what process is being a jerk and holding up the show? I suspect it is a network related system process.

I've never had any luck finding out what code is stopping the whole system while it's (probably) waiting to timeout. I suspect that's because that sort of thing isn't very transparent on modern multitasking OSs.

I once had a program that could tell you the last thing the CPU was chewing on before a system crash but it turned out that the ASUS P5As ALi chipset were just cheap and had some flaws.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special application for this task, that's exactly what the **Windows Task Manager** is meant for. It will tell you what processes your computer is struggling with in terms of CPU activity, disk activity, memory usage etc. Watch for any of these parameters hitting high level when your system is unresponsive, and you probably know the reason why. If it's just Chrome that needs a lot of resources, and no other application, try using less plugins or tabs in Chrome.

In case there is no specific application having a lot of CPU, Memory or Hard Disk activity, make sure that your hardware specifications are OK to run Windows 10. You should have enough free memory available, at least about 1GB free during regular use of your computer. Otherwise, your system has to swap out memory contents to the hard disk, which slows your computer a lot. Also make sure that your disk activity is low most of the time, if it isn't, that's a sign of your hard disk being to slow.

You won't get any other information then to use system tools to track down your issue, since this is not the [Software Reccommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Its a netbook with SSD and Win10 preinstalled. Task manager is for noobs. It don't show what dependency is causing the holdup. but thanks for trying.